# C# : compiling with /debug+ /debug:pdbonly /optimize- is optimizing the runtime code

Tags: c#, optimization

is it a bug? here is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   fun1();
}
static void fun1()
{
  fun2();
}
static void fun2()
{
  throw new Exception("test exception");
}
```

build with the above option in VS 2008, with Optimize option not selected and Build advanced options debug info select pdbonly and check the stacktrace.

let me know u guys experience the same

Comment: This should not compile at all...

Comment: Can you first check that the code you've got here is correct. Should the throwing function be called fun2?

Comment: Have you run ildasm on the code itself and compare both the .il files (debug and optimize) to see any difference?

Comment: Your code is full of errors. Downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using /debug:pdbonly is enough to convince the compiler that its okay to inline methods.  It generates a different [DebuggableAttribute] into the assembly:

.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 00 06 01 00 00 00 00 )

Where /debug:full produces:

.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00 )

If this is a problem, you'll need to explicitly disable inlining like this:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void fun1() {
      fun2();
    }
```

Comment: This is strange that optimize- does not have any meaning when pdbonly debug mode is selected. If that is the case microsoft must document this under optimize help section

Comment: Moreover its not the compiler which inlines the methods - its at runtime JIT does that job. Compiler just adds the attributes to instruct JIT to do the inlining

Comment: Thats true - anyways i assume that the pdbonly takes preference than optimize for now :)

Comment: Meh, the JIT always inlines when it can.  Unless explicitly told not to by attributes.